# Is there an event or way to know when a Chrome Extension has been toggled on or off in the Extensions page?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, listener

I've got a Chrome Extension that has been working fine so far.
When the extension is installed or started up, it needs to load some settings.
So I have been using this in my background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(loadSettings);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(loadSettings);
```

Basically it runs the loadSettings() function to intialize the extension.

I've just come across an unexpected situation and after doing some research I could not find an answer.
It seems that when the extension is toggled off, the background page's loaded settings and variables are unloaded.
How can you know if the extension has been toggled off and on in the Chrome Extensions page? (at chrome://extensions/)

Comment: When the extension is turned off it can't run anymore. The only part of it that still remains is a content script in a matching tab (until the tab is navigated away or reloaded). The content script can detect the fact that the extension is disabled by periodically sending a dummy message and checking chrome.runtime.lastError in the callback. Anyway, what does loadSettings initialize specifically?

Comment: Good information.  What's most important is to know when the extension is toggled back on, so that it can check for the stored variables using chrome.storage.  It needs those so it can check the previously stored state of the extension, as in if it was supposed to be running, disabled, other, etc.  Then it can do things such as update the browser action icon title and icon, make the extension work based on the saved settings, etc.  Without an event to get those stored variables, the extension is stuck with the default settings, and not the stored settings.

Comment: You'll either have to remove `"persistent": false` in manifest.json (and put the code to read the state at the start of the script) or rework your extension to do stuff only in an event listener like chrome.tabs.onUpdated and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When an extension is disabled background scripts should stop execution, extension pages are closed and content scrips lose access to the communication to the background scrips.

Inside your content scrip you can listen to the disconnection even like:

`chrome.runtime.connect().onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
    console.log('disconnected');
    location.reload();
});`

Comment: That's interesting, but what I really want to know is when the extension is toggled back on.  That's because the settings that were loaded in the background page when it was installed or started up are not available anymore, and it's not clear how to load these settings again after the extension was toggled back on.

Comment: @theMaxx any update on this? Is there an event when the extension starts?